# How to manage GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithEmailAndPassword and setPersistence in Firebase 9?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I have an application that logs in both by email and password and by GoogleAuth, but after logged in, if the user reloads the page, it logs out.

I'm trying to manage `GoogleAuthProvider`, `signInWithEmailAndPassword` and `setPersistence`. For this example, just follow the login function with Google. I did it as follows:

**Login.vue**

```js
import { getAuth, setPersistence, inMemoryPersistence, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup, } from "firebase/auth";

googleSignIn: function() {
   const auth = getAuth();
   const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
   signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
     .then(() => {
       setPersistence(auth, inMemoryPersistence);
       this.$router.push("/");
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       // error messages
       }
     });
},
```

I'm trying to apply what I saw here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

On the other hand, in the parent component (after logging in), I'm getting the user data without any problems as follows:

**Header.vue**

```js
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

export default {
   date: () => ({ username: "" }),
   created() {
     const auth = getAuth();
     onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
       if (user) {
         this.username = user.displayName;
       } else {
         this.username = "logged out";
       }
     });
   },
};
```

#### EDIT

I'm including the data saved in the application here. Even so, when reloading the user logs out.

[image: Console Application]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the intended behavior. You are setting auth persistence to `inMemoryPersistencce`. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence#supported_types_of_auth_state_persistence) says,

> `NONE` (`inMemoryPeristence`) indicates that the state will only be stored in memory and will be cleared when the window or activity is refreshed.

Try setting the persistence to `SESSION` or `LOCAL`.

---

If I open dev tools, I can see I am authenticated. The issue seems to be with your redirect here:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // This currentUser maybe undefined
  const currentUser = getAuth().currentUser;

  // ...
  else next();
});
```

Try using `onAuthStateChanged()` in the `beforeEach`:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const auth = getAuth()

  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (!user) return next("login"); 
  })
})
```

Comment: @Arnon can you try setting the persistence before logging in? Make sure you have cleared browser cache. The `setPersistence` returns a promise so handle that using await or promise chainging

Comment: That's exactly my question. I tried to do it, but no success. You can check by yourself: https://livrero.vercel.app

Comment: @Arnon are you using `setPersistence` anywhere else ? Can you try copying code from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/DharmarajX24/d36c3022bf85a59a18ea2e1eb587a772) ?

Comment: No, `setPersistence` is only  in `Login.vue`. Tried this gist but logs out when reload. Full code is here in [GitHub](https://github.com/arnonrdp/Livrero).

Comment: @Arnon `setPersistence` returns a Promise. You are not using await [here](https://github.com/arnonrdp/Livrero/blob/fb14761b85e84b4afb382fc4d1abdab5ea1de22a/src/views/Login.vue#L116)

Comment: Yeah, I removed to try other things. I just added again and deployed so you can try.

Comment: @Arnon can you check the updated answer and try using onAuthStateChanged?

Comment: Yeah, I am doing some tests here in my localhost and the problem really seems to be inside `router.beforeEach `. With this update the reload does not logs out but the first access to page `("/")` (after a session clean) doesn't redirect to login. Console detected a Stack Overflow: infinite redirection in a navigation guard when going from "/" to "/login".

Comment: @Arnon it is ... try `console.log(getAuth().currentUser)`

Comment: Returns `null` when I clean session and `UserImpl {providerId: 'firebase', emailVerified: true, isAnonymous: false, tenantId: null, providerData: Array(1), …}` after login.

Comment: @Arnon what does it log on refresh?

Comment: Returns `null` after refreshing.

Comment: @Arnon even after using onAuthStateChanged?

Comment: Oh, no I am sorry. I placed `console.log` at the wrong place. Now this is returning a `UserImpl`. But it just works when I user a `else next()` inside the `onAuthStateChanged`. But if the user doesn't have a session, it returns a Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't know why but it worked doing this: `if (to.meta.requiresAuth && user == null) { next({ name: "Login" })  } else { next() }`. So I accepted you answer because it is very near to what I needed.

Comment: I'm not sure where is requiresAuth coming from but if user is null they should be redirected to login.

Answer (score 2):

On browser environments the default behavior for Firebase Authentication is to persist the user authentication state between page loads, and there is no need to call `setPersistence` yourself. I recommend removing this call from your code, and leaving it to the Firebase SDK to use its defaults.

Comment: I tried. But when the page is reloaded, it logs out.

Comment: "it logs out" is not very clear. When you reload the page, your `onAuthStateChanged` listener should get called after a few moments with a valid `user`. Does that not happen for you? If so, does it get called at all? Also: where are you running this code?

Comment: You are right, there is no need to call `setPersistence`. My problem was related to `onAuthStateChanged`.